# Массив целых чисел: TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, numpy

```
import scipy
import scipy.fftpack
import cmath 
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
from scipy import  signal
from scipy.signal  import freqs, iirfilter
xx = np.linspace(0, 1024, 1024) # диапазон значений x
byts = ([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
ff = 64 # %Частота несущей 
ns = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 1) * ff / 1024) # несущая
y = ns * byts[round(int(x + 31) / 64)] # %сигнал 
plt.plot(y)
```

Ошибка:

```
TypeError:  only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Как правильно нужно задать массив целых чисел `х`, чтобы не возникало данной ошибки?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Разберёмся, почему возникает данная [ошибка](https://ideone.com/n6wyh9). Посмотрим на выражение:

```
round(int(x + 31) / 64)
```

`x + 31` это массив длины 1024, а мы его приводим к `int`'у и непонятно, что должно получиться в результате. Python так и говорит:

> TypeError:  только массивы длины один могут быть приведены к скалярному типу (int это скалярный тип)

Уберём приведение к `int`'у:

```
y = ns * byts[round((x + 31) / 64)]
```

Ошибка пропадёт, но появится [другая](https://ideone.com/zvUd5g):

> TypeError: type numpy.ndarray doesn't define __round__ method

Можно заменить [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) на [`np.round`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.round_.html):

```
y = ns * byts[np.round((x + 31) / 64)]
```

Мы получим другую [ошибку](https://ideone.com/jwx3Le):

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Дело в том, что `np.round((x + 31) / 64)` это массив, с типом элементов float, а мы используем этот массив как массив индексов, а индексы могут быть только целыми. Нужно изменить тип элементов массива с помощью [`astype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html):

```
y = ns * byts[np.round((x + 31) / 64).astype(int)]
```

Мы опять получим другую [ошибку](https://ideone.com/P64dro):

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Дело в том, что `byts` это обычный массив, и через квадратные скобки нельзя обращаться с массивом индексов. Сделаем `byts` numpy-массивом:

```
byts = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
```

Наша следующая [ошибка](https://ideone.com/MsO4m9):

> IndexError: index 16 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 16

Возникает из-за того, что в конце массива `np.round((x + 31) / 64` есть элементы, равные 16. Возможным решением будет изменение типа элементов массива `x` на `int`:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 1023, 1024).astype(int)
```

и замена сложного выражения `np.round((x + 31) / 64` на простое `x // 64`:

```
y = ns * byts[x // 64] # %сигнал
```

Итоговый код:

```
import scipy
import scipy.fftpack
import cmath 
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
from scipy import  signal
from scipy.signal  import freqs, iirfilter
x = np.linspace(0, 1023, 1024).astype(int) # диапазон значений x
byts = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
ff = 64 # %Частота несущей
ns = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 1) * ff / 1024) # несущая
y = ns * byts[x // 64] # %сигнал
plt.plot(y)
```

Comment: отличный ответ! и добавить нечего...